# How do I send an email when a value has been changed?

Tags: infopath, email, forms-services

I have an InfoPath web based form that has a few email addresses set up in different sections of the form. I want the Submit action to send an email to the changed email address only and not all. Is that possible?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with an automatically triggered Workflow, w/o any coding. Just create a WF with SharePoint Designer.